# Change SharePoint Online Site/SharePoint Subscription Edition Site language programmatically on user action

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are busy with migrating site with customization from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Online or SharePoint Subscription Edition.

Among the developments we had in SharePoint 2013 we have an application that allowed users to switch UI language between EN/FR/NL using a dropdown.
This was done using an HTTPModule and a custom cookie that was being set on language change. The dropdown for changing the language was installed using
SuiteLinkBarDelegate.

We have upgraded the solution to be able to install it to SharePoint Subscription Edition but HttpModule does not seem to be taken into account and
of course the SuiteLinkBarDelegate does no longer work eighter.

We have also tried to create an extension that would allow the user to chage the language but it seems more complicated than expected.

Does anyone have experience with this or can suggest anything else for this other than asking the user to change the language eighter from profile or browser?
Also explaining what goes on behind the scenes (cookie/local storage/session -wise and not the simple theory about which language is picked for the user)
would be of great help.

Thank you in advance for all your ideas, suggestions and help.

Example on how the SP2013 language switcher looked like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was your old solution based on PointFire, or completely custom?  They do have a SharePoint Online version.

Behind the scenes, the way it is done on premise is typically by having the httpmodule change the language by changing the thread UI culture before SharePoint starts generating the page.  That is not possible in SharePoint Online.  You could create an app or an add-in to change the user's language in their profile, but that takes a while to work, it is not an immediate change.